# Erro DLL inválida - System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: .net, exceção, dll

Pesquisei e encontrei que a exceção BadImageFormatException é lançada quando a imagem do arquivo de uma DLL ou programa executável não é válida. Como resolver?

Log do erro:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.BadImageFormatException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.

Erro de Origem: 

Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

Rastreamento do Carregamento de Assembly: As informações a seguir podem ser úteis para determinar por que o assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' não pôde ser carregado.


=== Informações sobre estado pré-associação ===
LOG: DisplayName = Flir.Atlas.Image
 (Partial)
AVI: informação de associação parcial foi fornecida para um assembly:
AVI: Nome do Assembly: Flir.Atlas.Image | ID do Domínio: 2
AVI: uma associação parcial ocorre quando somente parte do nome de exibição do assembly é fornecida.
AVI: isso pode fazer com que o associador carregue um assembly incorreto.
AVI: é recomendável fornecer uma identidade textual totalmente especificada para o assembly,
AVI: que consiste no nome simples, na versão, na cultura e no token de chave pública.
AVI: Consulte o white paper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 para obter mais informações e soluções comuns para o problema.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/reitz/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/IdReitz/IdReitz/IdReitz/
LOG: PrivatePath inicial = C:\Users\reitz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\IdReitz\IdReitz\IdReitz\bin
Chamando assembly: (Unknown).
===
LOG: esta associação começa no contexto de carregamento default.
LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de aplicativo: C:\Users\reitz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\IdReitz\IdReitz\IdReitz\web.config
LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de host: C:\Users\reitz\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: usando arquivo de configuração da máquina de C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: a política não está sendo aplicada para referência neste momento (particular, personalizado, parcial ou associação de assembly baseada em local).
LOG: tentando download de nova URL file:///C:/Users/reitz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/817d1970/36aa406f/Flir.Atlas.Image.DLL.
LOG: tentando download de nova URL file:///C:/Users/reitz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/817d1970/36aa406f/Flir.Atlas.Image/Flir.Atlas.Image.DLL.
LOG: tentando download de nova URL file:///C:/Users/reitz/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/IdReitz/IdReitz/IdReitz/bin/Flir.Atlas.Image.DLL.
ERR: falha ao concluir configuração do assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing encerrado.

Rastreamento de Pilha: 


[BadImageFormatException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Acho que faltam informações, consegue dar mais informações sobre o erro? Logs, crashlog, stacktrace....?

Comment: @Vinícius atualizei a pergunta com o log do erro.

Comment: O erro pode ocorrer por varios motivos. O arquivo está danificado, a DLL é de uma versão diferente da que ele espera, o arquivo é de 32bits e ele - o programa - espera 64bits ou vice-versa.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo a mesma dll tem para duas versões estou usando 64bits